ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_openai' on using Flask
Langchain was not recognized although I installed the necessary libraries.
I use Flask framework and want to integrate it with ChatOpenAI using Langchain.
I ran the command of langchain installation pip install langchain and pip install --upgrade langchain, the module is still not found.
Knowing that it works with normal IDE without Flask involvement.

Please update the question to add the output of this command pip show langchain and also the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)

LangChain does not import the Python package langchain-openai on default. What you need to do is to specifically add the package on your requirements or directly install it.
To install the latest version (at the time of my response), run:
pip install langchain-openai==0.1.6 

Then, you should be good to go and use the import langchain_openai package in your code.
